# Oracle Connection in ASP.NET 11g

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, odp.net

I am trying with a sample app to connect to Oracle 11g. The environment is Windows 2012 64 bit server. I ran into a weird loop of issues. The steps I followed are:

1. downloaded the ODAC 112040 XCopy (64bit) and installed all using batch file
2. Created a test windows forms application, referred the Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.4.0. It reported a warning with architecture difference between AMD and MSIL. The project was running with AnyCPU mode. Then I changed it to x64. It was working fine.
3. Next created a web forms application, referred the dll, it reported the same error, I changed it to x64. Then at run time, it threw "could not load file or assembly..." error.
4. After some googling, I downloaded ODP.NET (4.112.3.6) 64 bit and ran, Then it threw similar issue against Oracle.Dataaccess.

Please help resolving this issue.

Comment: remove Oralce.DataAccess.dll from your bin folder and try

Comment: Hmm... It does not exist in the bin folder.